# How to assign a class property passing value to class constructor using Dependency injection in spring?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am kind of super new to spring. I need to assign a value to my class property using the constructor. I am using the class constructor method in spring dependency injection to do that. How to configure bean XML to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyBean1.class:

```
  public class MyBean1{
      private MyBean2 bean2;
      public MyBean1(MyBean2 bean2){
         this.bean2=bean2;
      }
  }
```

XML:

```
  <!-- Definition for bean1 -->
   <bean id = "bean1" class = "com.MyBean1">
      <constructor-arg ref = "bean2"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- Definition for bean2 -->
   <bean id = "bean2" class = "com.MyBean2"></bean>
```